# qooxdoo: How to handle non build time plugins?

Tags: qooxdoo

Given the case that you have a basic GUI that must be extensible by plugins not known when the *generate* run of the main GUI is done. Contributable plugins may consist of some manifest, resources, localization, some code that is executable in the GUI environment and can provide custom widgets.

From what I see in the moment, it could be done by

- Let a plugin developer build against the ordinary source, generating a *part* for the plugin. Then manually register a `qx.io.part.Part` with the generated parts to the GUI running on the non developer side.
- Just load a combined source JS for that plugin, containing the resources and load them manually via `eval`.

I'd personally prefere the first one, as it already includes everything that might be used by a plugin. But it uses a method that is marked as *internal*.

Are there any experiences with that? Are there other, more elegant ways to achieve that?